# Cannot import pycaret in google colab

Tags: python, import, pip, google-colaboratory, pycaret

I cant import pycaret in a google colab

Here are all the steps I had taken:

Change python version to 3.8

Installed pip

I then ran

```
!pip install pycaret 
import pycaret
```

the install works, but then

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-fdea18e6876c> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install pycaret ')
----> 2 import pycaret

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycaret'
```

I must be doing something very wrong!

In troubleshooting I also pip installed numpy and pandas which both imported just fine

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For importing use this, this is one is for classification:

```
from pycaret.classification import *
```

And for regression:

```
from pycaret.regression import *
```

For NLP:

```
from pycaret.nlp import *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install --upgrade packaging -q
!pip install pycaret[full] -q
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install pycaret
```

should work without any issues. I have used it multiple times on Google Colab. Alternately, you can use

```
pip install --pre pycaret
```